# How to display props type table in storybook 6.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I'm creating ui-library for project (using Emotion), I added storybook with docs addon and I seems that storybook don't see props for styled component. How can I fix that?

```
"@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
"@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
"@storybook/react": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
```

// main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.@(tsx|mdx)"],
  // Add any Storybook addons you want here: https://storybook.js.org/addons/
  addons: ["@storybook/addon-docs", "@storybook/addon-knobs/register"],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
      loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
      options: {
        presets: [["react-app", { flow: false, typescript: true }]],
      },
    });

    config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");

    return config;
  },
};
```

// Example.ts:

```
import { ExampleProps } from "./Example.types";

export const Example = styled.div<ExampleProps>`
  color: ${(props) => props.color || "red"};
`;

export default Example;
```

// Example.stories.mdx

```
import { Meta, Story, Preview, Props } from "@storybook/addon-docs/blocks";
import { withKnobs, color } from "@storybook/addon-knobs";
import Example from "./Example";

<Meta title="Example" component={Example} decorators={[withKnobs]} />

# Preview

<Preview>
  <Story name="Example">
    <Example color={color('color', '#000', 'GROUP-ID1')}>Example</Example>
  </Story>
</Preview>

# Props

<Props of={Example} />
```

Unfortunately props table displays:

```
No inputs found for this component.
```

Comment: I'm having issues getting things working, but I'm using Flow rather than Typescript for types. However, this might help and I know it was something that I missed when looking at the docs myself.

In your MDX story, rather than using the `<Props of={Example} />` syntax, try using `<Props story='Example' />`. Note that we replace `of` with `story` and the value becomes the name of the story (used in the <Story /> tag) as a string rather than the component itself. I hope that helps. I know it did for me as the `<Props of={Example} />` syntax was not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since migrating to 6.0.0-rc.29.

I installed `storybook-addon-react-docgen` (v`1.2.42`) separately in package.json and now the props table has returned.

Also don't forget to add it to your addons array in main.js.

E.g. my main.js is

```
module.exports = {
stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.js'],
addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-knobs/register',
    'storybook-addon-react-docgen'
]
```